# PhD Program Academic Probation

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I'm an international student who starts a Ph.D. in fall 2021 (in a US university) in mechanical engineering. I took two courses which account for six credits (3 each) and three credits for research, a total of 9 credits for the semester.

At the end of the semester, I could not pass one subject (got an F), while on another subject, I had the best grade in the entire class (got an A). I'm on academic probation in Spring 2022 (again, taking two courses and doing research). I'm putting all my efforts into securing good grades this semester to remove my academic probation. However, I'm always stressed out about it, which somehow hampers my studies and research. I'm seeking any suggestions you may have. **Or should I drop my dream of pursuing a Ph.D., thinking perhaps the Ph.D. program is not for me?**

Answer (score 2):

You're doing what you can and what the probation conditions ask you to: Put your work into doing well in your classes. There is literally nothing more you can do, and in fact nobody is expecting you to do anything more. As a consequence, I can see no reason why you shouldn't stay in the program: Get through this semester, get good grades, get the probation removed, and move on.

It's far too early to throw in the towel yourself.